# Question about Dumps in Oracle (REMAP_SCHEMA)

Tags: oracle, dump

To export a dumpfile, I can:

```
EXPDP system/Password@TNS 
DUMPFILE=FileName.dmp 
Schemas=TheSchemaIWantToDump 
DIRECTORY=dumpdir
```

So, let's say I want to restore this DMP file, but with a different name (I'm a SQL Server Dba, and I'm still learning some Oracle). I would do this:

1)create a new user

2)GRANT CONNECT to this user

3)

```
IMPDP System/Password@TNS 
dumpfile=ThefileName.dmp 
REMAP_SCHEMA=OldUser:NewUser 
directory=dumpdir
```

My question is about REMAP_SCHEMA.When I'm restoring schemas inside my own server, I know the OldUser , so I can fill it, and then :NewUser.

But if I'm sending this dump file to our client. Should I mention this OldSchema?  They don't know the schema's name I'm using before the dump. Because on SQL Server I can RESTORE DATABASE , then name with the name a want FROM DISK....

How can I restore a schema with a different name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if not told, `OldUser` can be easily found as:

```
IMPDP System/Password@TNS 
dumpfile=ThefileName.dmp 
directory=dumpdir
sqlfile=ThefileName.sql
include=user
```

This does not import anything, just creates `ThefileName.sql` under `dumpdir` with the SQL statements used for creating `OldUser`, including the username as well of course. Using that information, they will know what to specify in `REMAP_SCHEMA=OldUser:NewUser`.

Comment: Thank you Balazs. So a good pratice is, to run EXPDP with the schema about to be dumped? I mean..I run EXPDP with SYSTEM ( `EXPDP SYSTEM/PASS schemas=TheSchemaIwantToDump` ). Should I `EXPDP Schema/;pass` so they can run the above IMPDP and get the right schema?

Comment: @RacerSQL It does not matter. The information will be stored in the dumpfile